# Is there any way to combine a fixed width box and a dynamic width box with customtkinter in Python?

Tags: python, user-interface, customtkinter

I try to make a layout like the following using `CtkFrame` from `customtkinter`:

| Box 1 | Box 2 |

Box1: width 200px, height expand to full height.

Box2: expand to full height and width

```py
import customtkinter as ctk

window = ctk.CTk()
window.geometry('800x600')

# has wrong size, but 200px is defined
box1=ctk.CTkFrame(window,width=200)

# Solution
box1.pack_propagate(False)

box1.pack(side=ctk.LEFT, fill=ctk.Y)

label1=ctk.CTkLabel(box1,text='box1')
label1.pack(expand=True,fill=ctk.BOTH)
label1.configure(bg_color='#345')

box2=ctk.CTkFrame(window)
box2.pack(side=ctk.LEFT, expand=True, fill=ctk.BOTH)

label2=ctk.CTkLabel(box2,text='box2')
label2.pack(expand=True,fill=ctk.BOTH)
label2.configure(bg_color='#543')

window.mainloop()
```

I tried a lot of things like pack and place, but i don't get the result what I want, I also think that grid won't work either, because there is no way to set a column to a fixed size, and I don't get the fixed 200px width for box 1 in combination with the 2nd box which should fill the rest.